# Matlab subplots squeezed

Tags: matlab, plot

I try producing a 14 x 5 subplot in Matlab, however the subplots have square axes so when displayed the subplots are not legible. Similarly, when I plot the results to pdf, the subplots are too small to read. How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to increase the size of the text? What do you mean by "not legible"?

Comment: I usually make many separate subplots. Say, 14 1x5s. Unless you have a very high resolution screen, I don't see how you are going to make your plots visible (at least with the MATLAB default settings).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your subplots to be squished when you print them to pdf, you can increase the size of the "paper" you're printing them to. Execute the following code before printing:

```
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches');
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [12 12]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
```

"This ensures that the printed version is the same size as the on-screen version." (from Matlab-help for print)